# C++ redefining an included Class

Tags: c++, class, compilation, include

So I have 3 classes Vehicle, Linked_List, and TrafficSim
Each class has both a .cpp and .h file

TrafficSim.h has:

```
#include "Linked_List.cpp"
#include "Vehicle.cpp"
```

Linked_List.h has:

```
#include "Vehicle.cpp"
```

and all fo the cpp files have:

```
#include "File.h"
```

All of my H files have guard that goes:

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H
/* code for class function declarations */
#endif
```

For some reason, after compiling Im getting an error sayng I am redefining Vehicle, so Im guessing the guard I was taught to set up, does not work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is the `.C` or `.CPP` files that implement classes which `#include` the `.H` header files that declare the classes, and not the other way around, as you appear to be trying to do.